# int array gives crazy values unless all fields initialized to 0, why?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

```
int TwoThrows();


int main(){

        int Throws, Throw, Frequency[13]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        randomize();


        cout << "\nThis program simulates throws of two dice.";
        cout << "\n\nHow many throws : ";
        cin >> Throws;



        // Calls TwoThrows and saves in Frequency by value
        for(int I=0; I<Throws; I++){
                Throw=TwoThrows();   //2-12
                Frequency[Throw]++;   //2-12

        }

         // Prints array:
        for(int I=0; I<11; I++){
                cout << I+2 << ":\t" << Frequency[I+2] << "\n";

        }

        return 0;
}

int TwoThrows(){
        unsigned int I=(random(6)+1)+(random(6)+1);

        return I;

}
```

This prints:

2:      1317
3:      2724
4:      4145
5:      5513
6:      7056
7:      8343
8:      6982
9:      5580
10:     4176
11:     2776
12:     1388

Which is great.

However, what I want to know is, why did I have to set the array to {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}?

If I do NOT do that; i get:

2:      30626868
3:      1638233
4:      844545295
5:      1
6:      9
7:      4202510
8:      4199197
9:      844555757
10:     3
11:     4202574
12:     2130567168

Comment: What would you have expected to get?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I would expect to get the proper distribution without initalizing it. Is this a limitation with Borland C++ builder 5, or is this how C++ always works?

Comment: Take note that `Frequency[13]={0}` would also suffice to say "make them all zero".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't initialize the array, and then proceed to increment its elements, technically this is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What happens in practice is that the array's elements get whatever values happen to be on the stack when `main()` starts.

Comment: I see. Is there a simpler way to initalize it to all elements zero, or do I have to do it this way, or perhaps using a for-loop in multiple dimensions.

Comment: @DrOnline: Since this is C++ and not C, just use `std::vector<int>`. It can easily initialize all the values upon construction.

Comment: @DrOnline: `int Frequency[13] = {};`

Comment: @NPE I would, if this was a personal project, but I'm doing this in college (small class introducing us to programming), and we haven't covered vectors, classes etc, so I feel I should solve the problem using methods covered by the curriculum. Thanks though!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Compiler did not like that.

Comment: @DrOnline: There is a number of shortcuts you could take because the values are zero. However, a simple and general solution is to write a `for` loop. I doubt your tutor would object to that.

Comment: @DrOnline: What was its complaint?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(11): E2264 Expression expected

Comment: @DrOnline `int a[13] = {};` is perfectly valid C++. It is strange that it doesn't compile. Could you try `int a[13] = {0};`?

Comment: @DrOnline: Either you're doing something else wrong, or your compiler is broken.  Does this program work for you? http://liveworkspace.org/code/2bzDgB$0 -- If it doesn't, your compiler is broken.

Comment: @juanchopanza {0} worked fine. I am using an old program, Borland C++ Builder 5.0 (from 2000), it's the default one we're using. I normally use Dev-C++, but Borland had built in randomize() and random() which Dev-C++ did not have, which I need.

Comment: @DrOnline I see. If you don't care about the quality of the speudo-random number distributions you could probably achieve the same with `std::srand` and `std::rand`. If you have C++11 then you can use the new [pseudo random number generation facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Same error, the compiler is probably achaic.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, I did consider using vectors and that mersenne twister, but I felt it introduced more obstacles than it was worth, for this pretty simple paper I have to hand in. I'll learn proper methods as a hobby later on.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables are put on the stack of the function. This area is not initialized by the compiler or the operating system. This means that the values of local variables are exactly what's in the memory when the function is called, which is unlikely to be something you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate  an array you got place in  memory so this place could be used before by anther application,So if don't initialize that place it would give you unexpected values according to which application was using that place.

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand it this way. All memory locations are charged and when we assign a specific memory location to a variable, it will translated the raw value that the location was holding, also referred to as **garbage** value and hence we get unexpected values.

But when you initialize a variable or array, the default garbage values are replaced with the designated values and we get the desired output.

Hope this helps.