# Why int ia2[10] has a default value of 0 even though it is defined inside a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, undefined, default

I'm new to C++ and is trying to learn the concept of arrays. I saw the code and statement below from C++ primer.

> As with variables of built-in type, a default-initialized array of
>   built-in type that is defined inside a function will have undefined
>   values.

Judging from this statement, the `int ia2[10]` below is define inside the int main(){} function and therefore should not have default value and all its elements should be undefined. However, when I tried to print out their value, they are all equal to 0, which is the default value for any uninitialised int array.

Why is this happening?

```
int main() {
    string sa2[10]; //all elements are empty strings
    int ia2[10]; //all elements are undefined

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << "sa2[" << i << "] " << sa2[i] << endl;
        cout << "ia2[" << i << "] " << ia2[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sa2[0] 
ia2[0] 0
sa2[1] 
ia2[1] 0
sa2[2] 
ia2[2] 0
sa2[3] 
ia2[3] 0
sa2[4] 
ia2[4] 0
sa2[5] 
ia2[5] 0
sa2[6] 
ia2[6] 0
sa2[7] 
ia2[7] 0
sa2[8] 
ia2[8] 0
sa2[9] 
ia2[9] 0
```

Comment: 0 is an undefined value

Comment: Someone else got the exact opposite result, expected 0 and got garbage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450405/int-array-gives-crazy-values-unless-all-fields-initalized-to-0-why?rq=1.

Comment: Depends on compiler to some degree, some implement extensions, f.e MSVC in Debug mode fills with characteristic value 0xCE

Comment: More interesting will be such test: move this code to normal function (not main) and execute few times. Maybe memory for your program is cleared on init, Agree, this is Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't forced to have some random value. It's undefined what value will be there, so it could be anything, including all zeroed out. Also note that reading the value is undefined behavior.